# permalink to discussions and individual rows

Tags: smartsheet-api, smartsheet-api-1.1

We using the Smartsheet API to make information in Smartsheet searchable. So we need to link to individual entities in Smartsheet like sheets, reports and workspaces. And all those have permalinks to them, but entities inside sheets like discussions and rows cannot be uniquely referenced in a URL AFAIK. Is this not supported?

Please consider adding more permalinks to entities like discussions and rows if these are not already supported, it would make integrations like ours way more "targeted" than just pointing to sheets or workspaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stein - you are right, we don't currently support discussion or row permalinks.  Understand and appreciate your use case and it's high on the list, although don't have an ETA at this time.

Comment: Great, glad to hear that :-)  Do you have a mailing list or RSS feed for API changes?

Comment: Stein - we communicate our API changes via Twitter @smartsheetapi, but looking into adding other notification / subscription options.